# PrimeNG: Align listbox and panel next to each other

Tags: primeng

I use PrimeNG Beta 17 integrated in my Angular 2 app.
Within my template I want to place a listbox next to a panel, whereas the listbox shall appear left to the panel.

```
<p-listbox [options]="modelTypes" [(ngModel)]="selectedModelType"
           [style]="{'width':'150px','max-height':'150px'}"></p-listbox>
<p-panel header="Model description" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="true" >
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
</p-panel>
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?
I am aware of the "float" technique in CSS, however I wonder if there is any built-in support in PrimeNG to ease layouting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to archieve this, try using the Grid. 
So you just need to do something like this:

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
            <div class="ui-g-6 ui-g-nopad">
                Content1
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6 ui-g-nopad">
                Content2
            </div>
        </div>
```

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/grid